# Passing 2D array to a function without using vectors

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program to print the sum of the elements of a user entered square matrix in the form of a 2D array without using vector. However I am getting 2 errors:

- Error 1:  `error:array has incomplete element type 'int []'`.
- Error 2:
  `error: expected expression cout<<sumarr(arr[][]`

This is my program:

```
int sumarr(int arr[][])                 // ERROR 1
{
    // finging no. pf rows(or coloums) of the square matrix
    int n = sizeof(arr) / (2 * sizeof(int));
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)         // calculating sum of elements
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int n;                            // No. of rows(or coloumns) of the square matrix
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)   // inputting array elements
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << sumarr(arr[][]);          // ERROR 2
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone suggest why I am getting these errors and how to resolve them?

Answer (score 1):

In the function parameter (Error 1) you'll need to specify at least the last dimension of the array:

```
int sumarr(int arr[][SIZE]){ /*...*/}
```

In the call to the function you need to use the array name only, no dereferencing necessary (Error 2):

```
cout << sumarr(arr);
```

The problem then becomes the fact that [Variable Length Arrays are not allowed in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/6865932), so you probably should rethink the possibility of using vectors for this task.

Another thing worth mentioning is that `sizeof(arr)` inside the function will not render you the size of the array but the size of the pointer, [which is what `arr` becomes when passed as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/6865932).

Alternatively you can manually allocate memory for the array, it could look more or less like this:

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/WjqjKEqTz)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
```

```
// since sizeof arr can't work you should pass the size as argument
int sumarr(int **arr, int n) 
{
    assert(n > 0 && n < 1000); // confirm that n is valid, > 0 and a suitable upper limit
    
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //calculating sum of elements
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            // input and sum in the same loop will save you a O(N^2) operation
            std::cin >> arr[i][j];
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }       
    }
    return sum;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int n; //No. of rows(or columns) of the square matrix
    std::cin >> n;

    // memory allocation for 2D array
    int **arr = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[n];
    }
    //end
    
    int sum = sumarr(arr, n); // passing array and size
    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum;
     
    // freeing memory after use
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete [] arr[i];
    }
    delete [] arr;
    //end
}
```